# Add Business/working days in datetime column using Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

i need a postgresql method who can take two parameters date and noofdays and method can add only business days as noofdays in date.

prototype of method

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AddBusinessDays 
(    
    WorkingDays As Int
    Date as timestamp
)
```

Comment: To clarify, you're looking to pass in a timestamp and an integer where the integer is x number of days away from the given timestamp. Then determine how many business days are in that time span? Is it not possible to pass two timestamps?

Comment: for the reference you can see this function it's take two parameters and done the trick.
CREATE FUNCTION[dbo].[AddBusinessDays](@Date date,@n INT)
RETURNS DATE AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @d INT;SET @d=4-SIGN(@n)*(4-DATEPART(DW,@Date));
RETURN DATEADD(D,@n+((ABS(@n)+@d-2)/5)*2*SIGN(@n)-@d/7,@Date);
END

Comment: Here is the thing that i found.

create or replace function add_business_day(from_date date, num_days int)
returns date
as $fbd$
    select d
    from (
        select d::date, row_number() over (order by d)
        from generate_series(from_date+ 1, from_date+ num_days* 2+ 5, '1d') d
        where 
            extract('dow' from d) not in (0, 6) 
        ) s
    where row_number = num_days
$fbd$ language sql;